# Insert into fusion table using post command java - 414 Request-URI too large

Tags: java, http-post, uri, google-fusion-tables

I am attempting to update a fusion table row in java with a post command generated using the httpRequestFactory in the form below.

```
httpRequestFactory.buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl,null);
```

Where the GenericUrl will be something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/queryINSERT INTO -table string- (name,geom)
VALUES ('sedgewich county','<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
<coordinates>-102.650938,40.74916,0 -102.651013,40.752116,0 ........</coordinates>
</LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>');
```

ONLY the kml polygon string is THOUSANDS of characters long.

The problem is that when the post is executed I receive a 414Request-URI too large error. I didn't think this problem could occur on a post request.

I can insert a custom smaller kml string fine using the same methods, it just gives me the error when the kml string gets too long.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If you [read the documentation for insert commands](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/insert) it says "In the **request body**, supply _whatever_ resource with the following properties", so move your values into the body.

Comment: So I'm trying to insert the sql into the HttpContent but it wont let me create it, java keeps saying that the class is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to get the sql statement in the body of the post instead of the URL? Still having trouble with this...